# How to run multi programs in linux system

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

I am trying to run codes from the console on a linux system: Three simple programs. Here is the code I use

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <chrono> 
#include <thread>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: cpu <string> \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *str = argv[1];

    while(1){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); 
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with

```
gcc -o cpu cpu.c -Wall
```

And I want to run the codes as the book said.

```
prompt> ./cpu A & ; ./cpu B & ; ./cpu C & ; ./cpu D &
[1] 7353
[2] 7354
[3] 7355
[4] 7356
A
B
D
C
A
B
D
C
A
C
B
D
...
```

Now I get errors like this

```
bob@bobvm:~/codes/OS_3_pieces$ ./cpu A & ; ./cpu B & ; ./cpu C & ; ./cpu D &
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

My OS environment is Ubuntu 20. I guess the reason is that there is a different way to run multi process in Ubuntu system.  But I didn't find it. So how to run the codes to have same output as the book displayed?

Comment: Please remove your common header, do not use Spin function, rather 
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to improve your question, see comments above.

However, I also provide an answer. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. And it has nothing to do with your actual code. There are various ways how you can start programs on a linux shell.

- `./prog` just starts prog and then returns to shell
- `./prog &` starts prog and returns to shell immediately -- while it is running in background
- `./prog1 ; ./prog2` starts prog1, and when finished starts prog2
- `./prog1 & ./prog2 &` starts prog1 in background and immediately prog2 in background (so both are running in parallel)
- `./prog1 && ./prog2` starts prog1 and when finished without error ONLY then start prog2

And there are others I did not list here. Of course my examples are just for two programs, the number can be arbitrary. Also each program may have parameters.

From this, it is rather obvious what is wrong in your case. You cannot combine `&` and `;` -- for your purpose you just want the `&`.

Comment: or you can open 3 terminals